# Model the shape of a pendant drop

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear, singularity

When I tried using `NDSolve` to solve a set of differential equations modeling the shape of a pendant drop, I encountered `Power::infy`, `Infinity::indet` and `NDSolve::ndnum` warning, and the output just prints the original code and does not solve the equation. Why is this so?

Code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
a = NDSolve[{
   phi'[s] == 2 - z[s] - Sin[phi[s]]/r[s],
   r'[s] == Cos[phi[s]],
   z'[s] == Sin[phi[s]], r[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, phi[0] == 0}, {phi, r, 
   z}, {s, 0, 10}]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @xzczd, thank you for your help xiexie. The model that i am using is trying to model the shape of a pendant drop (search: pendant drop surface tension measurement), and the differential equation is like this from various sources. perhaps i can set my range of s to start from a non zero value

Comment: OK, so the `r[0]` is always possitive. Then the result given by `r[0] == 10^-3` should be reasonable.

Comment: Is it possible to plot z[s] on the y axis and r[s] on the x axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm… it's a bit surprising to me a single `SolveDelayed -> True` / `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` isn't enough to resolve the problem:

```
neweq = (Subtract @@ (phi'[s] == 2 - z[s] - Sin[phi[s]]/r[s]) // Together // 
    Numerator) == 0
{phisol, rsol, zsol} = 
 NDSolveValue[{neweq, r'[s] == Cos[phi[s]], z'[s] == Sin[phi[s]], r[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, 
   phi[0] == 0}, {phi, r, z}, {s, 0, 10}, SolveDelayed -> True]
ParametricPlot[{rsol[s], zsol[s]}, {s, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The option `SolveDelayed -> True` is red, but don't worry. If you don't like it, use `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` instead.

Alternatively we can modify the initial condition(s) a bit. The easiest choice is:

```
{phisol, rsol, zsol} = 
 NDSolveValue[{phi'[s] == 2 - z[s] - Sin[phi@s]/r[s], r'[s] == Cos[phi@s], 
   z'[s] == Sin[phi@s], r[0] == 10^-3, z[0] == 0, phi[0] == 0}, {phi, r, z}, {s, 0, 10}]
```

The modification `r[0] == 10^-3` is acceptable but not mathematically strict. A more formal treatment is to find the asymptotic solution at $s \to 0$ first and modify the initial conditions accordingly:

```
eq = {phi'[s] == 2 - z[s] - Sin[phi@s]/r[s], r'[s] == Cos[phi@s], z'[s] == Sin[phi@s]};

asol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{eq, r[0] == eps, z[0] == 0, phi[0] == 0}, {phi, r, z}, 
  s -> 0]

lb = 10^-3;

newbc = Through[{phi, r, z}[s]] == asol /. s -> lb /. eps -> 0

{phisol, rsol, zsol} = NDSolveValue[{eq, newbc}, {phi, r, z}, {s, lb, 10}]

ParametricPlot[{rsol[s], zsol[s]}, {s, lb, 10}]
```

The solutions are virtually the same.