# Intermediate variable changes the solution

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

I found a very weird error while numerically solving ODEs using the shooting method and I have no clue of the origin.
Fortunately, I knew my former result is incorrect, and I found how to resolve it by accident, but I want to make sure I will not face this kind of error in the future case when I don't even know whether my result is correct or not.

This is my former code

```
P = 1; 
Σ = -1.1 P^(2/3);
C0 = 0;
spsoln = NDSolve[{Z'[s] == -Sin[ψ[s]], ψ''[s] == -ψ'[s]/X[s] Cos[ψ[s]] + Cos[ψ[s]] Sin[ψ[s]]/X[s]^2 + γ[s]/X[s] Sin[ψ[s]] + P X[s]/2 Cos[ψ[s]], γ'[s] == (ψ'[s] - C0)^2/2 - Sin[ψ[s]]^2/(2 X[s]^2) + 
 P X[s] Sin[ψ[s]] + Σ, X'[s] == Cos[ψ[s]], ψ[0] == 0, ψ'[0] == 1/2.2, X[0] == 0.0000000001, γ[0] == 0, Z[0] == 0}, {X, ψ, Z}, {s, 0, 10}];
RevolutionPlot3D[Evaluate[{X[s], Z[s]} /. spsoln], {s, 0, 6.91}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

By analytically solving, this is supposed to be a sphere solution, but you will find this ends up with an oblate. Instead, if I double psi'[s] value, i.e.,

```
ψ'[0]=1/1.1,
```

then it gives me a sphere.

However, if I slightly change this code without touching the physical meaning by introducing U[s]=psi'[s] as follows,

```
P = 1;
Σ = -1.1 P^(2/3);
C0 = 0;
spsoln = NDSolve[{U[s] == ψ'[s], Z'[s] == -Sin[ψ[s]], ψ''[s] == -ψ'[s]/X[s] Cos[ψ[s]] + Cos[ψ[s]] Sin[ψ[s]]/X[s]^2 + γ[s]/X[s] Sin[ψ[s]] + P X[s]/2 Cos[ψ[s]], γ'[s] == (U[s] - C0)^2/2 - Sin[ψ[s]]^2/(2 X[s]^2) + P X[s] Sin[ψ[s]] + Σ, X'[s] == Cos[ψ[s]], ψ[0] == 0, U[0] == 1/2.2, X[0] == 0.0000000001, γ[0] == 0, Z[0] == 0}, {X, ψ, Z}, {s, 0, 10}];
RevolutionPlot3D[Evaluate[{X[s], Z[s]} /. spsoln], {s, 0, 6.91}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

it results in a sphere solution as expected. Basically, they are the same ODEs, but they give different results. Can anyone figure out why? and how to prevent this in general?

Thank you

Comment: Note re [tag:bugs]: "This tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions."

Comment: I get an error when I evaluate the code that produces a sphere. It seems to me that the error is a sufficient indication that something has gone wrong. If you change `\[Psi]''[s]` to `U'[s]`, then error goes away, and the oblate spheroid returns.

Comment: Also, notice the problem is not related to `"Shooting"` method. `"Shooting"` method is **only** for solving boundary value problem (BVP), while your constraints are all setting at `s==0`, so this is an initial value problem (IVP). In former case `NDSolve` is using an ODE solver, while in latter a DAE solver, and as pointed out by @Michael , the warning `NDSolve::ivres` is suspicious enough. It's not immeditely clear to me where the inconsistency is, though.

Comment: The inconsistency is probably `ψ''[0]`. If you substitute i.c.s into the equations, you'll find `ψ''[0]==-4.545454545*10^9`, but the DAE solver ignores this and turns to something close to `0`. BTW, it's better to add some background info of the system to the post. Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/253316/1871

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks for many comments.
@MichaelE2 Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't know about the tag. I agree that the error is a sufficient indication. The thing is I have no idea what to do to fix it...

Comment: @xzczd I used the terminology "shooting method" in the sense that I am varying U(0) value and looking for the right value that satisfies the end-point boundary conditions. For this case, 1/2.2 was just one of the solutions that I was looking for. But this may be irrelevant to the code itself. Thanks for the comment and link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me extend the comments to an answer.

> I knew my former result is incorrect…

No, though it's not the expected solution, it's correct. You obtain this undesired solution because you've modified the initial condition

```
X[0] == 0
```

to

```
X[0] == 0.0000000001
```

Indeed, this is a widely-adopted method for avoiding singularity, but in certain cases it can cause surprisingly large error. ([Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103685/1871)'s another example. )

Then why does 2nd approach happen to give the desired solution? As pointed out by 
[Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258067/error-with-ndsolve-with-shooting-method#comment643539_258067), the warning message

> NDSolve::ivres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended.

is already a sufficient indication. Just check the function value at `s == 0` in 2nd case:

```
P = 1;
Σ = -1.1 P^(2/3);
C0 = 0;
dae = {U[s] == ψ'[s],
      Z'[s] == -Sin[ψ[s]],
     ψ''[s] == -ψ'[s]/X[s] Cos[ψ[s]] + 
       Cos[ψ[s]] Sin[ψ[s]]/X[s]^2 + γ[s]/X[s] Sin[ψ[s]] + P X[s]/2 Cos[ψ[s]], 
      γ'[s] == (U[s] - C0)^2/2 - Sin[ψ[s]]^2/(2 X[s]^2) + P X[s] Sin[ψ[s]] + Σ,
      X'[s] == Cos[ψ[s]]};
soldae = NDSolve[{dae,
    ψ[0] == 0,
    U[0] == 1/2.2,
    X[0] == 10^-10,
    γ[0] == 0,
    Z[0] == 0}, {X, ψ, Z, γ}, {s, 0, 10}];

iclhs = Through[{X, ψ, ψ', Z, γ}[0]];

icdae = iclhs == (iclhs /. soldae[[1]])
(* {X[0], ψ[0], ψ'[0], Z[0], γ[0]} == 
   {-4.93347*10^-6, -2.24249*10^-6, 0.454545, -2.68851*10^-12, 5.5*10^-6} *)
```

It's clear the initial conditions (i.c.s) have changed. If you use these i.c.s for the original system:

```
eqold = {Z'[s] == -Sin[ψ[s]],
        ψ''[s] == -ψ'[s]/X[s] Cos[ψ[s]] + 
          Cos[ψ[s]] Sin[ψ[s]]/X[s]^2 + γ[s]/X[s] Sin[ψ[s]] + P X[s]/2 Cos[ψ[s]],
         γ'[s] == (ψ'[s] - C0)^2/2 - Sin[ψ[s]]^2/(2 X[s]^2) + P X[s] Sin[ψ[s]] + Σ,
         X'[s] == Cos[ψ[s]]};
soltest = NDSolve[{eqold, icdae}, {X, ψ, Z, γ}, {s, 0, 10}];

RevolutionPlot3D[Evaluate[{X[s], Z[s]} /. soltest], {s, 0, 6.91}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A sphere is obtained.

I'm not sure why the DAE solver of `NDSolve` makes the change in this case, but it may be related to precision and is not robust as an approach for obaining the sphere, because if you modify the i.c. `X[0] == 10^-10` to `X[0] == 10^-9`, `NDSolve` spits out `NDSolve::nderr` and fails.

Then how to obtain the desired solution in a robust way? The 2 methods mentioned in

[Model the shape of a pendant drop](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/253316/1871)

are applicable.

Method 1, transform the equation a bit and explicitly choose DAE solver:

```
help[eq_] := (Subtract @@ eq // Together // Numerator) == 0

sol1 = NDSolve[{eqold[[{1, 4}]], help /@ eqold[[{2, 3}]],
    ψ[0] == 0,
    ψ'[0] == 1/2.2 ,
    X[0] == 0,
    γ[0] == 0,
    Z[0] == 0}, {X, ψ, Z, γ}, {s, 0, 10}, SolveDelayed -> True];
```

Notice I've set `X[0] == 0`, there's no need to modify the initial value in this method.

Method 2, utilize asymptotic solution to obtain a more accurate approximation of the initial conditions:

```
asymsol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{
   eqold,
   ψ[0] == 0,
   ψ'[0] == 1/2.2 ,
   X[0] == eps,
   γ[0] == 0,
   Z[0] == 0}, {ψ, X, γ, Z}, s -> 0]

newic = Through[{ψ, X, γ, Z}[s]] == asymsol /. s -> 10^-3 /. eps -> 0

sol2 = NDSolve[{eqold, newic, ψ'[s] == D[asymsol[[1]], s] /. s -> 10^-3}, {ψ, 
    X, γ, Z}, {s, 0, 10}];
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I couldn't even follow your answer without searching for some commands and I've learned a lot from your answer. I will see which method could work better for my case. Thank you again.